# How to query multiple fields with Chewy

Tags: elasticsearch, chewy-gem

Let's say I have an index with multiple objects in it:

```
class ThingsIndex < Chewy::Index
  define_type User do
    field :full_name
  end 

  define_type Post do 
    field :title
  end
end
```

How do I search both users' `full_name` and posts' `titles`.

The docs only talk about querying one attribute like this:

```
ThingsIndex.query(term: {full_name: 'Foo'})
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways you could do this. Chaining is probably the easiest:

`ThingsIndex.query(term: {full_name: 'Foo'}).query(term: {title: 'Foo'})`

If you need to do several queries, you might consider merging them:

```
query = ThingsIndex.query(term: {full_name: 'Foo'})
query = query.merge(ThingsIndex.query(term: {title: 'Foo'}))
```

Read more about merging here: [Chewy #merge docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/toptal/chewy/Chewy/Query#merge-instance_method)

Make sure to set your limit or else it only shows 10 results:

`query.limit(50)`